# ng-if is not updating according to the variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm starting with AngularJS and I'm doing a simple application to learn it,

In my app, I have four tabs: List, Create, Update and Delete

But I just want to show the tabs Updade and Delete if I hit the button in the list section.

I did a factory to set the tab state to true or false. When I hit the button, the state is changed but the tabs does not update. Can any one help me please?

Here is my tab factory:

```js
angular.module('primeiraApp').factory('tabs', [TabsFactory])

function TabsFactory(){

   function show(owner, {
      tabList = false,
      tabCreate = false,
      tabUpdate = false,
      tabDelete = false
   }) {
      owner.tabList = tabList
      owner.tabCreate = tabCreate
      owner.tabUpdate = tabUpdate
      owner.tabDelete = tabDelete
   }

   return { show }
}
```

Here is my Controller:

```js
angular.module('primeiraApp').controller('BillingCycleController',[
  '$http',
  'msgs',
  'tabs',
  BillingCycleController
])

function BillingCycleController($http,msgs,tabs){
    const vm = this
    const url = 'http://localhost:3003/api/billingCycles'

    vm.refresh = function (){
      $http.get(url).then(function(response){
        vm.billingCycle = {}
        vm.billingCycles = response.data
        tabs.show(vm,{tabList: true, tabCreate: true})
      })
    }

    vm.create = function(){
      $http.post(url,vm.billingCycle).then(function(response){
        vm.refersh()
        msgs.addSuccess('Operação realizada com Sucesso')
      }).catch(function(response){
        msgs.addError(response.data.errors)
      })
    }

    vm.showTabUpdate = function(billingCycle){
      vm.billingCycle = billingCycle
      tabs.show(vm, {tabUpdate : true})
      console.log("List: "+vm.tabList+"\nCreate: "+vm.tabCreate+"\nUpdate: "+vm.tabUpdate+"\nDelete: "+vm.tabDelete)
    }

    vm.showTabDelete = function(billingCycle){
      vm.billingCycle = billingCycle
      tabs.show(vm, {tabDelete : true})
      console.log("List: "+vm.tabList+"\nCreate: "+vm.tabCreate+"\nUpdate: "+vm.tabUpdate+"\nDelete: "+vm.tabDelete)
    }

    vm.refresh()
}
```

And where is my HTML:

```html
<content-header name = "Ciclo de Pagamentos" small = "Cadastro"></content-header>

<section class="content">

  <div class="nav-tabs-custom" ng-controller= "BillingCycleController as bcCtrl">
    <ul class = "nav nav-tabs">

      <li ng-if= "bcCtrl.tabList">
        <a href data-target = "#tabList" data-toggle="tab">
          <i class = "fa fa-bars"></i> Lista
        </a>
      </li>

      <li ng-if= "bcCtrl.tabCreate">
        <a href data-target = "#tabCreate" data-toggle="tab">
          <i class = "fa fa-plus"></i> Incluir
        </a>
      </li>

      <li ng-if="bcCtrl.tabUpdate">
        <a href data-target = "#tabUpdate" data-toggle="tab">
          <i class = "fa fa-pencil"></i> Editar
        </a>
      </li>

      <li ng-if= "bcCtrl.tabDelete">
        <a href data-target = "#tabDelete" data-toggle="tab">
          <i class = "fa fa-trash-o"></i> Deletar
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div class = "tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane" id= "tabList"  ng-if= "bcCtrl.tabList" ng-include = "'billingCycle/list.html'" ></div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id= "tabCreate" ng-if= "bcCtrl.tabCreate" ng-include = "'billingCycle/form.html'"></div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id= "tabUpdate" ng-if="bcCtrl.tabUpdate" ng-include = "'billingCycle/form.html'"></div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id= "tabDelete" ng-if= "bcCtrl.tabDelete"  ng-include = "'billingCycle/form.html'"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Here is what I got in the console

When I hit Edit:
[image: Click Update button]

When I hit Delete:
[image: Click Delete Button]

Does anyone can say what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `I'm starting with AngularJS` no point of starting with angular1.x

Comment: ng-if can return true if object exists or if false, try ngif="var===true"

Comment: I already tried it, bt nothing, I also put a <p >{{bcCtrl.tabUpdate}}</p> and so on, this isn't updating as well

Comment: Could you deploy your code to jsfiddle or smth similar?

Comment: Damn so strange  code bro..  use $scope in your controller set these variables to $scope and then try again

Answer (score 0):

use ng-show instead of ng-if .

Comment: try $scope.$apply() after updating

Comment: why $scope.$apply ? This is all inside angular context

Answer (score 0):

I solve it.

There was a file called list.html
it was like this:

```html
<div class="box-body" ng-controller = "BillingCycleController as bcCtrl">
  <table class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <tr>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Mês</th>
      <th>Ano</th>
      <th>Ações</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="billingCycle in bcCtrl.billingCycles">
        <td>{{billingCycle.name}}</td>
        <td>{{billingCycle.month}}</td>
        <td>{{billingCycle.year}}</td>
        <td class="table-actions">
          <button class = "btn btn-warning" ng-click="bcCtrl.showTabUpdate(billingCycle)"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
          <button class = "btn btn-danger"  ng-click="bcCtrl.showTabDelete(billingCycle)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I just removed `ng-controller = "BillingCycleController as bcCtrl"` from the first line and the problem was solved. This happened cause my tabs.html was calling list.html, and by putting `ng-controller` inside list.html I was creating another instance of BillingCycleController.

After the change, my source got like this :

```html
<div class="box-body" >
  <table class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <tr>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Mês</th>
      <th>Ano</th>
      <th>Ações</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="billingCycle in bcCtrl.billingCycles">
        <td>{{billingCycle.name}}</td>
        <td>{{billingCycle.month}}</td>
        <td>{{billingCycle.year}}</td>
        <td class="table-actions">
          <button class = "btn btn-warning" ng-click="bcCtrl.showTabUpdate(billingCycle)"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
          <button class = "btn btn-danger"  ng-click="bcCtrl.showTabDelete(billingCycle)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Thanks for everyone that tried to help me